# Angular 2 HTTP- Post

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, angular4-httpclient

I am have facing little strange behaviour in angular 2 HTTP post

```
public post(_ApiUrl: string, _Body: string): Promise<any> {
    let token = this.storage.getauthToken();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")
      .set('authorizationToken',token)
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.post(_ApiUrl, _Body, {headers}).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log("rest::post::error::" + JSON.stringify(err));
      });
    });
}
```

In the above Code observe the header **authorizationToken**, i am passing token to the header. But response returns with

> Failed to load resource: Origin http://localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

But if i replace `.set('authorizationToken',token)` with `.set('authorizationToken',1234)` direct token value i am able to fetch the result from my server.

I am unable to understand the weird behaviour. Can anyone help me out

Comment: It looks like you will have a problem with CORS, can you show a screenshot of the network tab from your browser, to let us know how request looks.

Comment: What is the return type of `this.storage.getauthToken()`? Can you provide the network request headers as they appear for the request that works and the one that doesn't?

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel, its a String. for example like 'papdkfapdkfpksdfks' this.

Comment: please refer [https://www.dropbox.com/s/gifekh7mjucw50m/Screen%20Shot%202018-04-18%20at%2011.18.59%20PM.png?dl=0] for an image.

Comment: Did you properly configure CORS on the back-end?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle this if you have control of the responding server is to add a response header for:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

You can just put the Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *